# Dynamic disclaimer on transaction form html/pdf

Tags: netsuite

I'm having some issues with making the disclaimer (or message!) on the transaction forms dynamic. I basically need it to show a different message based on the state of the shipping address (which is an issue in itself).

I'm having a tough time with any examples or docs. I'm either looking in the wrong place, or just not understanding it. They are currently using the legacy basic forms, which probably doesn't help.

These are the options.. I think:

1) I need to write a script to parse the shipping address as retrieved by an API call, then I figure I could use the setFieldValue to set the value of the disclaimer? Or set it to a custom field and display that?

2) Use an Advanced HTML/PDF form and do a hardcoded if statement.. maybe? tbh I'm not even sure how I can get the state, as all the address fields I have seem to be just 'Address'.

Unless I'm barking up the wrong tree and it's much simpler than that altogether. I've kinda been chucked in the deep end, having had no NS experience before!

If anyone has an examples, that'd be swell.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: your questions already seems to have the answer. #2 would be a preferred approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think both your options are spot on.  If I had to do this, I would probably do point 2, only because I like the HTML option and flexibility of Advanced HTML/PDF.  To get the state, you can can use: **${record.billaddress}** or **${record.shipaddress}** as part of your if statement and then put the html of your disclaimer.

Another option if point 1 and 2 doesn't float your boat, is to create separate forms with different disclaimers on each of the forms...although this seems like a lot of rework.

Just some options.  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks. Think I'll go option 2. Could you explain the 3rd option for me a bit more? I understand the logic, but the users currently print sales orders off... and it seems you can't choose which template to use? (Sorry I'm from a Salesforce world, where it's a lot more intuitive, and thats saying something)!

Comment: Ian, it means you could have a form attached to each "state".  And a different PDF format/layout per PDF.  Each of these layouts would have a different disclaimer.  You could then put a script/workflow in place that whenever someone saved the transaction, it would automatically set the form based on the "state" on the address.  And when they user prints, it will print the correct form/disclaimer accordingly.

Comment: Oh blimey, a tonne of work then. lol. Thanks for your help Lez.

Answer (score 1):

Does the disclaimer have to appear when the User is creating the transaction?

If you need it in the UI, then you will need to use option 1.

If you just want the disclaimer to show on the PDF, then option 2 like Lez Yeoh said is the best.

Comment: I should have explained a bit better. It's on the back of a webstore, so all the transactions are already made. The users then print off the PDFs to go in the boxes etc. I think Option 2 is probably better long run! Thanks for your reply!